# How to send a file over a network using socket channel in java

Tags: java, sockets, channel

I want to write a socket channel program using which I can send a file from the client program to the server program. I want to create this program using Java.

Is there any other on-line help is available
So how to overcome this problem.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could clarify you question. Do you just want to send a file in a convenient way? Then I'd strongly recommend some standard protocol, such as [SSH File Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol). This is much preferrable to using some home-grown code, allows you to use existing solid libraries and makes interoperability with other software easier.

Since you asked specifically about a socket channel program: Is this a homework question? In that case I'd advise you to read the Javadocs for the SocketChannel class, and google a bit for example code using it. If you then still have a problem, post another question with the *specific* thing you don't understand, and we'll probably help :-).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!

First you need to change the file into bytes...

then from `OutputStream` ...you can write the Bytes into the server....